# Google Cloud PubSub - can't seem to get topics

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, gcloud-node

I'm using heroku to run a node.js app that uses gcloud to create a topic, and then subscribe to it. I'm using the following code, as taken from here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.16.0/pubsub

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud')({
  keyFilename: 'pubsub_key.json',
  projectId: 'pipedrivesekoul'
});

var pubsub = gcloud.pubsub();

//create a new topic
pubsub.createTopic('projects/pipedrivesekoul/my-new-topic', function(err, topic, apiResponse) {
  var topic = pubsub.topic('my-new-topic');
  topic.publish({
    data: 'New message!'
  }, function(err) {console.log});
});

  var topic = pubsub.topic('my-new-topic');



// Without specifying any options.
topic.subscribe('newMessages', function(err, subscription, apiResponse) {});

var alltopics = pubsub.getTopics({}, function(err, topics, nextQuery, apiResponse) {});

console.log(pubsub.getTopics({}, function(err, topics, nextQuery, apiResponse) {}));
```

However, when I deploy on Heroku (https server, registered on Google Console, with the correct APIs deployed and the appropriate key in a json file), instead of seeing a list of topics, it just returns 'undefined':

> 2015-07-24T18:06:05.321079+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
>
> 2015-07-24T18:06:05.337947+00:00 app[web.1]: Node app is running on port 36252

Not sure why this might be happening and not too sure how to debug this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spotted a couple issues which will hopefully clear this up.

```
pubsub.createTopic('projects/pipedrivesekoul/my-new-topic'
```

You only need to provide the `my-new-topic` part. The ugly, long title is sent automatically.

```
console.log(pubsub.getTopics({}, function(err, topics, nextQuery, apiResponse) {}));
```

This is actually logging the result of calling

```
pubsub.getTopics({}, function(err, topics, nextQuery, apiResponse) {})
```

Which is `undefined`. Instead, try:

```
pubsub.getTopics({}, function(err, topics, nextQuery, apiResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(topics); // hopefully in this array is one called `my-new-topic`
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much - I can get a list of topics now. I'm trying grant publish rights to a topic using SetIamPolicy as I've described here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599021/google-cloud-pub-sub-api-push-e-mail/31599464#31599464] but no success yet - not sure what the exact call should look like. For now I've made a json file as described here: [https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push] and call it like this: `topics.SetIamPolicy('pubsub_policy.json');` - but topics is undefined. Any ideas? Googling has yielded absolutely nothing in terms of examples in node.js...