# Using Pubsub to push Gmail in node.js - How to set publish rights?

Tags: node.js, publish, publish-subscribe, gmail-api, policy

I'm trying grant publish rights to a topic using SetIamPolicy as has been described here: [[Google Cloud Pub/Sub API - Push E-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599021/google-cloud-pub-sub-api-push-e-mail/31599464#31599464]) but no success yet - not sure what the exact call should look like.

For now I've made a json file containing this:

```
POST "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1beta2/{resource=projects/myproject/topics/mytopic}:setIamPolicy"
Content-type: application/json

{
  "policy": {
    "bindings": [{
      "role": "roles/pubsub.publisher",
      "members": ["serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com"],
    }],
  }
}
```

as described here: http://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push and call it like this: `topics.SetIamPolicy('pubsub_policy.json');` - but setiampolicy is an undefined function. Any ideas? Googling has yielded absolutely nothing in terms of examples in node.js

Comment: Have you replaced `{resource=projects/myproject/topics/mytopic}` with a real value? E.g. `projects/gmail_client/topics/gmail_push_notif`?

Comment: Yes, I have replaced it with `{resource=projects/gmail_client/topics?gmail_push_notif}` and have also tried with the `{resource=` part - then i pasted the exact code above into a json file and call it with 'topics.setIamPolicy('pubsub_policy.json');`.... really not sure how this is supposed to work though, any help, even at a basic level, would be appreciated!

Comment: * without the resource part

Answer (score 2):

## I used the Google Developers Console

After a lot searching I found it was easier to just set the publish rights in the Google Developers Console.

1. click on your project
2. click on **Big Data** > **Pub/Sub**
3. If you haven't already done so, create a topic
4. Check the box next to that topic
5. Click the permissions button at the top
6. Add your permissions in the box that should look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZcd9.png)

I did find [this documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.24.1/pubsub/subscription?method=iam.setPolicy) about **setIamPolicy()** for nodejs.

```
var myPolicy = {
   bindings: [
     {
        role: 'roles/pubsub.subscriber',
        members: ['serviceAccount:myotherproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com']
     }
   ]
};

topic.iam.setPolicy(myPolicy, function(err, policy, apiResponse) {});

subscription.iam.setPolicy(myPolicy, function(err, policy, apiResponse) {});
```

But I couldn't get it to work.  **topic.iam.setPolicy()** didn't exist.  All I saw was this:

```
//console.log(topic)
{
    ...
    iam: { 
         resource: 'projects/[projectId]/topics/[topicName]',
         makeReq_: [Function] } 
}
```